# How to logout and display message after login under certain condition?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Given a Drupal 7 website I want to customize log in behavior: When a users logs in I want to check if they are in a blacklist. If they are in that list I want them to be automatically logged out and told about the reason they are being kicked out. So In one of the custom modules of this drupal I have add the following hook:

```
function mymodule_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  if(blacklist(&$edit, $account)) {
    drupal_goto("/user/logout/");
    drupal_set_message('Acces denied','error');
  }
}
```

However, my code doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong? I'm sure the hook is executed because I checked this using a watchdog. However, I also discovered the hook only gets executed if admin is the user who is logging in.

Are there any alternatives (maybe using Context module)? Any suggestions would be aprreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not work because [drupal_goto()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) calls [drupal_exit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_exit/7) so the rest of your script does not get executed.

What you are trying to do will not work because [user_logout()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.pages.inc/function/user_logout/7) itself calls drupal_goto() to the front page. 
You can however add an extra validation callback in the user login form so you can prevent users from logging in altogether.

```
<?php
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'user_login':
    case 'user_login_block':
      $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_custom_user_validation',

    break;
  }
}

function mymodule_custom_user_valudation($form, &$form_state) {
  if (// Add your blacklist conditons here. ) {
    form_set_error('', t('Your account is blacklisted, therefore you cannot login to this account'))
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! You saved me a lot of time. Your solution is clear and simple and that's what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If your interested in using the [Login Destination](http://drupal.org/project/login_destination) Module, then you could create some type of rule to hook into your blacklist check and then redirect that user to the "user/logout" path.  Let me know if you have any questions.

What exactly is your "blacklist()" function doing?

Comment: My blacklist function asks Salesforce if user is blacklisted given its username/email. Thanks for your answer.